# How to have multiple base classes for Spring Data JPA repositories?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I develop an application to store different time series, e.g. temperature, pressure, etc. So I have a base class for all these measurements:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "f_id")
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

    @Column(name = "f_location_id")
    private UUID locationId;

    @Column(name = "f_time")
    private long time;

    // getters and setters  
}
```

I need a common repository method to get one measurement, which is prevous to passed time, like:

```
public T getPrevious(T entity) {
   "SELECT e FROM " + entity.getClass().getSimpleName() + " e WHERE e.time <= :time "
   // only query example here to get you an idea.
}
```

I followed Spring docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories

However, that section tells us how to make **all** repositories to have that method, but I don't need **all** (I defenityle don't want my LocationRepository to have that method). I don't want to implement that method for each measurement entity either.

What should I do?

### Answer

Accepted answer is correct, but I want to publish all my code as it shows how to autowire `EntityManager` and how to get needed repository by entity class in runtime.

```
public interface TemperatureRepository extends TimeSeriesCrudRepository<Temperature> {}

public class TemperatureRepositoryImpl extends TimeSeriesRepositoryImpl<Temperature> {
    public TemperatureRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityManager);
    }
}

// this interface is needed to use any TimeSeries repository in common way
@NoRepositoryBean // annotation important
public interface TimeSeriesCrudRepository<T extends TimeSeriesEntity> extends TimeSeriesRepository<T>, CrudRepository<T, UUID> {}

public interface TimeSeriesRepository<T extends TimeSeriesEntity> {
    void getPrevious(T entity);
}

public class TimeSeriesRepositoryImpl<T extends TimeSeriesEntity>  implements TimeSeriesRepository<T> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public TimeSeriesRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public void getPrevious(T entity) {
        // impl
    }
}

@Service
public class RepositoriesService {

    private Repositories repositories = null;

    @Autowired
    public RepositoriesService(WebApplicationContext appContext) {
        repositories = new Repositories(appContext);
    }

    // this explains why we need TimeSeriesCrudRepository - to return generic interface with both common CRUD and custom meth
    <T extends TimeSeriesEntity> TimeSeriesCrudRepository<T> getRepository(T entity) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        return (TimeSeriesCrudRepository<T>) repositories.getRepositoryFor(entity.getClass());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add custom implementation for just the repositories you need [as explained in the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour).

---

Let us say you have these base entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "f_id")
  private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class TimeSeries extends Entity {
  @JoinColumn(name = "f_location_id")
  @ManyToOne
  private Location location;

  @Column(name = "f_time")
  private long time;
}
```

---

the following concrete entities:

```
@Entity
public class Location extends Entity {}

@Entity
public class Temperature extends TimeSeries {}

@Entity
public class Pressure extends TimeSeries {}
```

---

and the following base repository interfaces:

```
public interface EntityRepository<T exends Entity> extends CrudRepository<T, UUID> {}

public interface TimeSeriesRepository<T extends TimeSeries> extends EntityRepository<T> {}
```

---

Then, the repository interface for `Location` (and similar entities) would simply be defined as:

```
public interface LocationRepository extends EntityRepository<Location> {}
```

and so on.

---

Custom behaviour can be added just for the descendants of `TimeSeries` as:

```
public interface CustomRepository<T extends TimeSeries> {
  T getPrevious(T entity);
}

public abstract class CustomRepositoryImpl<T extends TimeSeries> implements CustomRepository<T> {
  public T getPrevious(T entity) {
    ...
  }
}

public class TemperatureRepositoryImpl extends CustomRepositoryImpl<Temperature> {}

public interface TemperatureRepository extends TimeSeriesRepository<Temperature>, CustomRepository<Temperature> {}

public class PressureRepositoryImpl extends CustomRepositoryImpl<Pressure> {}

public interface PressureRepository extends TimeSeriesRepository<Pressure>, CustomRepository<Pressure> {}
```

---

**Note:** If the repository for `Temperature` is called `TemperatureRepository`, the additional custom behaviour must be implemented by a class named `TemperatureRepositoryImpl`, and so on. This is explained in the official documentation under the section linked at the top. This will force the Spring Data infrastructure to automatically discover the custom implementation classes and inject the custom behaviour at runtime.

Comment: So, no need in `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = "...")`?

Comment: Nope, Spring Data infrastructure will automatically wire things up, provided you implement things **exactly** as I have posted.

Comment: And I need `Impl` class for each TimeSeries subtype repository, right?

Comment: Yes, because you want custom behaviour for only specific repositories, not all. Spring Data JPA supports customization either for all repositories at a time or on a one-to-one basis. There is no "add custom behaviour for this group of repositories".

Comment: Yes, I've just tried - this works. But I still had to improve your code, as I need `EntityManager` in my custom realizations. I'll update my question a few moments later.

Comment: Sorry, I was blind. Answer is quite complex, one little mistake and all crashes.

Comment: You can inject `EntityManager` into the custom repository implementation class. See [my sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/42456821) for details on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The solution described in spring docs can still be used to provide custom methods to a subset of your repositores **if** you can have your repositories in separate packages.

You'd just need to specify `<jpa:repositories ... />` once per package with different `base-class` attributes.

The following tells spring to use the default base-class for all repositories living in `com.example.repositories.std` and my own custom base-class for repositories living in `com.example.repositories.special`.

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.repositories.std"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.repositories.special" base-class="com.example.repositories.special.MyBaseRepositoryImpl"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" />
```

Important: the "special" package cannot be nested inside the "std" package, of the repositories will be served by the default base class.