# Is it possible to implement a generic repository for an abstract entity?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, generics, java-11

I have been messing with java generics and spring-boot and I'm trying to implement the following, but I'm not happy with the solution that I achieved for now

Let's say it that I have two entities: Cat and Dog (basic pojo classes).

Cat refers to table on database A, Dog refers to a table on database B.
For the future, I want to move Cat to database b (creating a new table for it), but for now I want to keep as it is. So I want to work with both entities seamlessly.

I have an abstract class Animal, that both Cat and Dog extend from it (for avoiding repetition of shared properties between classes).

Now comes the fun part: I don't want to call on the service class the repository for persisting specifically cat and dog (like CatRepository and DogRepository). I want to find a way to implement a *generic * "AnimalRepository" that will know, when persisting an entity, which correspond repository it is linked (like Cat -> CatRepository).

I kinda achieved what I want with this:

```
@Repository
public interface AnimalRepository <T extends Animal> extends JPARepository<T,Long>

T findByTag();
...
```

```
@Repository
public interface DogRepository extends AnimalRepository<Dog>

//implementation of common method for specific entity
Dog findByTag(String tag);
...
```

```
@Repository
public interface CatRepository extends AnimalRepository<Cat>

//implementation of common method for specific entity
Dog findByTag(String tag);
...
```

And then have a service where I just:

```
@Service
public class AnimalService{

private final AnimalRepository<? extends Animal> animalRepository;

@Autowired
public AnimalService(AnimalRepository<? extends Animal> animalRepository){
this.animalRepository = animalRepository;
}


public saveSubclassEntity(Animal animal){
if(animal instanceof Dog){
DogRepository dogRepository = animalRepository;
animal = dogRepository.save(animal);
}else{
CatRepository catRepository = animalRepository;
animal = catRepository.save(animal);
}
```

Because of the ambiguity in not specifying (or not knowing how) which repository should be "used" for the entity in question, I have to have this block of code to know where to persist the entity according to the instance that it is.

Do you have any idea or tip (or maybe a better solution for this problem) for me?

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: You solution seems rasuable to me. I just recommend you to put `T findByTag(String tag)` method in `AnimalRepository`, then you don't have to specifically implement it in each repository.

Comment: I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545276/how-to-implement-a-spring-data-repository-for-a-mappedsuperclass) is asking for a similar thing. Also, I wonder if you could make `Animal` into an `abstract @Entity` with `TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance strategy. This way, you wouldn't even need separate repos for `Cat` and `Dog` and only interact with `AnimalRepository` instead. That might require both tables to come from the same schema, and for IDs to not overlap, though

Comment: (depending on the RDBMS used, the first problem might be solved using aliases)

Comment: This question may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456821/how-to-have-multiple-base-classes-for-spring-data-jpa-repositories

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the Animal related classes abstract might be the best way to go.
AbstractAnimalService has CatService and DogService as implementations.

And when you have to work with them, you only have to worry about autowiring the correct one and assign it to type AnimalService (this could be the common interface).

This will give you felxibility with minimal code duplication.

Cat and Dog classes will diverge at some point.
If you believe they won't, then you probably don't even need the Cat and Dog implementations, all you need is Animal.

Keeping AnimalService abstract gives you the felxibility to override the behaviour in Cat and Dog service when needed.

I'd do the same with the entities and repositories.
We follow this same design where i work.